# Select sibling of parent on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to change the css of `.target` that is the sibling of the parent of `.hover`. Can't seem to get this code to work - I'm not sure if I need $(this) at the beginning of my function, or $('.target')... I think it might be .target because that is what I'm changing the css of with `.css()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).parent().siblings('.target').css('display', 'inline');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).parent().siblings('.target').css('display', 'none');
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

And here is my hunch (which also doesn't work):

```
$('.target').parent(this).sibling().css('display', 'inline');
```

And here is html

```
<div class="target" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div>
    <span class="hover">Hover</span>
</div>
```

EDIT-----------------
It seems that it doesn't work when a `span` is `class="hover"`.

EDIT numero dos --------------------
It seems that I had my `<span>` two parents deep and needed `.parent().parent()` Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling `.sibling()` (which doesn't exist) or `.siblings()` (which does)?

Comment: see the jsfiddle links posted, class="hover" works fine on a span :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andy,
Check this fiddle out, you seem to have the correct code in the first sample that you posted. If you could post your html, we might have a better time helping out. http://jsfiddle.net/nKtzB/3/

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your html is as you expect, and without seeing it I can't comment on improvements, this should work:

```
$('.target').parent().siblings('.target').css('display', 'inline');
```

Or, if the the `.target` element is the next sibling:

```
$('.target').parent().next('.target').css('display', 'inline');
```

Or, if the previous sibling (and from the html you posted it *is* the previous sibling):

```
$('.target').parent().prev('.target').css('display', 'inline');
```

References:

- [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`.sibling()`](http://api.jquery.com/sibling/).
- [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:block` instead, if you are trying to do something with the block.

Your code is still fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Mx4ks/1/

---

Something else must be wrong.. Try pasting your HTML too :)

See your own code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mx4ks/