# CSS next element (none sibling) selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<svg>
   <path/>
</svg>
<img/>
```

Is there a way to do something like "display:block;" to the <img/> when <path/> is hovered, with CSS only?

Comment: No, though depending on the actual svg and paths used, you could apply the hover to the `svg` ?

Comment: Extra reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Stop bringing in so many good comments so fastly I can only upvote every five seconds. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere Haha, I do apologise! I'll try to put the brakes on my awesome :p

Comment: SmokeyPHP, I cannot apply hover to `svg` because it is rectangular. I need hover on `path` because it is a curve. And if i put `img` after `path` Chrome renders it after the `svg`.

Comment: @Dmitry In which case as Pinocchio has answered, it is not possible with CSS only - however it can be achieved with JavaScript

Comment: SmokeyPHP, I know I could do `$('path').on('mouseover',function{$('img').show()});` and `$('path').on('mouseout',function{$('img').hide()});` but CSS would work faster.

Comment: @Dmitry CSS would be faster if it was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible if it is possible to select the parent of `<path/>` which unfortunately is not possible, so your answer is this is not possible.

If you would like to try this with javascript I can provide you a jQuery (not the best) example.

```
$('svg > path').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().next().addClass('hover');
}, function() {
   $(this).parent().next().removeClass('hover');
});
```

Then in your css you can do.

```
img.hover{
   // These styles take effect when you hover `<path>`
}
```

Comment: Note: the question as it currently stands indeed has an answer of `NO` as it specifies `CSS only`, but this can of course be achieved with JavaScript ([jQuery examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055830/select-sibling-of-parent-on-hover-with-jquery#answer-8055865))

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yeah, I know.

Comment: Yea, it was more for other viewers of this answer than it was for you.

Comment: Okey doke, added a simple jQ example